# QBChat Pending Contacts

Tags: quickblox

I am trying to access [QBChat instance].contactList.pending

It says that their is no object "pending" on the object QBContactList.

On your documentation page, it says that the above line "[QBChat instance].contactList.pending works.

The only two objects that can get called are: contacts and pendingApproval.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg,

Try adding the method:

```
-(void) chatDidReceiveContactAddRequestFromUser:(NSUInteger)userID {

    //insert functionality here

}
```

Make sure this is added to the file that is being used as your chat delegate. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
[QBChat instance].contactList.pendingApproval
```

Comment: The above method that I marked as correct seems to give me the users that have added me. The pendingApproval seems to give me the users that I have added.